# 4 Table depth mysql lookup

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have 4 tables - companies, projects, workers, tasks
Each company has several projects,
Each projects has several workers,
Each worker has several tasks.

In the tasks table, there is an "estimated_cost" field. I want to view the list of all the companies, but I want it sorted by the estimated_cost of the task with the highest estimated_cost within it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the highest estimated cost per company?

Comment: No. If one company has projects, workers, etc, and a task that its estimated cost is 1000$, and another company that has projects, workers, etc, and hundreds of tasks with an estimated cost of 999$, I still want to see the company with the 1000$ task first.


To clarify, I want to find the most expensive task per company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MSSQL not MySQL so the syntax may not be 100%... but try this.

```
SELECT company.name, MAX(estimated_cost) AS HighestCost
FROM companies 
INNER JOIN projects ON projects.companyid = projects.id
INNER JOIN workers ON workers.projectid = workers.id
INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.workerid = tasks.id
GROUP BY company.name
ORDER BY HighestCost DESC
```